# Parsing script tag content with nodejs and cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want the `sources` array of the configuration object passed to `jwplayer("vplayer").setup` using cheerio or some other module.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thevideos.tv/css/main.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" CHARSET="UTF-8"
            src="http://thevideos.tv/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 style="background:transparent;">

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            <div style="position:relative;width:728px;height:410px;">
                <div id="play_limit_box">
                    <a href="http://thevideos.tv/premium.html" target="_blank">Upgrade you account</a> to watch videos
                    with no limits!
                </div>

                <span id='vplayer'><img src="http://192.99.62.187/i/01/00077/u0mqgq67qz76.jpg"
                                        style="width:728px;height:410px;"></span>    
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script type='text/javascript'>    jwplayer("vplayer").setup({
    sources: [{
        file: "http://192.99.62.187/kj2vyrxjey6vtaw52apz4kuggj6xfcc27pjizr5rhnrcgv73id7wwhzxlqda/v.mp4",
        label: "240p"
    }, {
        file: "http://192.99.62.187/kj2vyrxjey6vtaw52apz4kuggj6xfcc27pjizr5rhfbsgv73id76twjcd2ha/v.mp4",
        label: "360p"
    }]
});
</script>

<script>
    var sid = 90446;
    var wid = 115535;
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can it be done using cheerio? If not what do I have to use and how?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `cheerio` to retrieve the contents of the script tag, but you'd have to parse the content yourself. This should work for you, assuming the relevant script tag is always served the way you described:

```
$ = cheerio.load(html);

var textNode = $('body > script').map((i, x) => x.children[0])
                                 .filter((i, x) => x && x.data.match(/jwplayer/)).get(0);

if (textNode){
    var scriptText = textNode.data.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "")
                                  .replace(/file:/g, '"file":')
                                  .replace(/label:/g, '"label":');
    var jsonString = /sources:(.*)}\);/.exec(scriptText)[1];
    var sources    = JSON.parse(jsonString);
}
```